# Magento 2 Override view/adminhtml/ui_component XML file of third party Module

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I am using Third Party Module for Admin section which used UI component to display data.The file path is

`Vendoname/Modulename/view/adminhtml/ui_component/news_data_listing.xml` file

.I want to override that file in our Custom module and display some more columns.

I have used same path and just copy paste that file and make some changes but these changes are not getting reflecting.

in Our Moudle file path is:

```
Vendoname/Mymodule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/news_data_listing.xml
```

What should Used to override the Extension file.If anyone have idea please share me.

Answer (score 3):

In your UI listing file, you should add the custom columns under the **columns** node and add the same name as in the 3rd party module's 'columns' node (so when files are loaded, the content is merged under the same keys).

For example my `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml` is adding the billing phone number column to the `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`:

```xml
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns">
        <column name="billing_telephone" sortOrder="60">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="validate-telephone" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Phone</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

and in order to ensure the proper module loading order position, in my `module.xml` file I have:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It also works for 3rd party module overriding. Just copy/paste the same folder path whatever we want to override (ui_component or templates or layout, etc.) and must be same file name.